# How to invoke descructor of static array in C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, g++-4.7

How can the following template function be implemented in C++11 in order to support array types as a template parameter? Currently compilation fails with the error as below. Is there some syntactic trick that works this around?

```
template<typename T>
void destroy(T &o) { o.~T(); }

int main()
{
    int x;
    char y[3];
    destroy(x);
    destroy(y);
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void destroy(T&) [with T = char [3]]’:
test.cpp:9:18:   required from here
test.cpp:2:26: error: request for member ‘~char [3]’ in ‘o’, which is of non-class type ‘char [3]’
```

Update:
if a buffer of wrappers like struct Storage { CharType value; } is used instead of CharType (i.e. Storage* instead of CharType*) then this could allow the destructor of the CharType = array be called via Storage::~Storage(). And this could work in the code that caused this question. However, the question remains: if it is allowed to invoke a destructor of a fixed-size array explicitly in C++ and if it is then how to do this?

Comment: Why are you manually calling the destructor? :(

Comment: Here is just a minimalistic version of what I need to do. In my code there is a dynamically allocated buffer (NOT with new T[]) so I need to destroy each element T allocated manually.

I know the descructors of POD types are no-op. But I need destroy(T &) be compilable for any type that has destructor visible to it, including POD types.

Comment: @dzidzitop: The minimal example doesn't include that fact: please make the objects dynamically allocated in your question.

Comment: Ok. Here is the code that does not compile: https://github.com/dzidzitop/libafc/blob/master/src/afc/FastStringBuffer.hpp

(afc::FastStringBuffer::~FastStringBuffer())

Comment: maybe you are better of using a `shared_array<>`... there is also the possibility to add a custom deleter function   -[boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)  - with c++11 you could also use `shared_ptr<T[]>`

Comment: Yes, something like this could be used. However, the question is rather about the C++ language itself, not about how to replace using the built-in arrays with classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be a bit more explicit for arrays and don't forget to pass them by reference to avoid array-decay:

```
template<typename T>
void destroy(T &o) { o.~T(); }

template<typename T, size_t N>
void destroy(T (&o)[N]) {
    for(size_t i = N; i-- > 0;)
        destroy(o[i]);
}
```

BTW: Calling the dtor is only supported for *type-names*. `int` is not a *type-name*. So, it's no hardship, because who would want to explicitly destruct an explicit fundamental type anyway?

Comment: In fast, if direct invocation of o.~T() (where o can be an array) is replaced with destroy(o) as written above then this helps to destroy a placement-allocated array of arrays (of objects) with minimal effort. However, array seems to have no desctuctor at all and is a very unusual type with respect to C++ semantics.

Comment: @dzidzitop: Yep, that's the reason I went for `destroy` there. As you say, the native array type in C and C++ is at best a second-class citizen, whose behavior for the most part emerges from array decay...